# fatal: Needed a single revision on homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to get my mac's brew to work properly.
When I want to make a `brew update` or another brew command like `brew install libomp`, I still have an error of the type

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

I have tried uninstalling and then installing brew several times.
I tried to `cd $(brew --repository) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` but nothing works.

If I do a command like `brew install libomp` I still get this error:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "libomp".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```